ORA-04098: trigger Schema.Trigger is invalid
I'm getting an error "ORA-04098: trigger Schema.Trigger is invalid".
Scenario is: In my DB, there are 3 schemas, S0, S1 and S2
Tables, Indexes, Sequences etc. are created in schema S0 and packages, views, Triggers etc. are created in S1 and S2.
S1 and S2 have rights to perform DML on S0's tables.
On update of Employees details trigger "Emp_Log_Change" will fire and the same trigger available in both the schema S1 and S2.
When both the triggers are in valid state then Oracle is allowing to perform DML(Update) on Employees and fire the trigger of same schema from where DML initiated.(e.g. If DML initiated by S1 then trigger of S1 gets fired.)
When one of the schema's trigger is invalid (say trigger of S2 is invalid) and I'm performing DML using S1 then it's throwing the error as mentioned above.
It's a valid case that Oracle is validating both the triggers because they are created on S0.Employees
So, My question here is: Is there any way that we can instruct Oracle not to validate all the triggers on tables and stick with the validation of same schema trigger from where DML initiated?
Performed below steps in DB as below:
Logged in using S0:
Create table Employees(Id Number(10), Name Varchar2(30), DeptId Number(10)); 
Grant Delete, Update, Insert On S0.Employees to S1,S2 With Grant Option;

Logged in using S1:
Create Or Replace Trigger Emp_Log_Change After Update On S0.Employees
For Each Row
Begin Dbms_Output.Put_Line(Sys_Context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') || ' fired');
End;

Logged in using S2:
Create Or Replace Trigger Emp_Log_Change After Update On S0.Employees 
For Each Row
Begin Dbms_Output.Put_Line(Sys_Context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') || ' fired');
End;

Executed below query using S1:
Insert Into Employees Values(1, 'ABC', 10);

Commit;

Update Employees Set DeptId = 20 Where Id = 1;

Output: S1 fired.

Commit;

Recompile trigger of S2 without semicolon (Just to make it invalid):
Removed ; from DBMS... statement.

Executed below query using S1 again:
Update Employees Set DeptId = 10 Where Id = 1;

Getting error this time because trigger of S2 is in invalid state.
Thanks in advance :)
Thank you!

Allowing different users to create triggers on a table they do not own is a bad idea. As you are experiencing, it only takes one mistake by one of those trigger owners and you have a Denial of Service on the table. When you grant privs to those users to create those triggers, you are trusting them to write good code.
Further, if the table owner were to drop a table (e.g. maybe replacing it with a new version and swapping the data out from the old segment for maintenance reasons), that will drop all triggers defined on it. The trigger owners will lose their code unless the table owner knows to script out those triggers ahead of time and recreate them afterwards, but they may not have permissions to do so outside the table schema. It's just asking for trouble to have cross-schema triggers like this.
Your only option is to disable (or drop) the bad triggers, or fix the compilation errors so that they are all valid. I would recommend overhauling the design so that such cross-schema triggers are not employed at all. You may want to reconsider why triggers are being used at all. They are supposed to be used to either add another layer of data consistency or maintain metadata (something only the table owner should have control over), and should not be used for normal programmatic job flow/control.

Approach to minimise the application downtime.

@pappukumar, can you elaborate? If you mean how to fix it with minimal change window, disable those bad triggers or fix them.

If no change in S0 then can patch one schema at a time and while patching of one another schema will run the application.

@pappukumar, what do you mean by "patch one schema" ? - this sounds like language specific to your business requirement, that we would not understand. What is the purpose of these cross-schema triggers? Why aren't the triggers owned by S0?

"patch one schema" means deployment of code changes. Both S1 and S2 have exactly same code. Our current strategy is divert the application traffic (application call from internet) to S2 and deploy the S1 changes, divert the traffic to S1 and deploy S2 changes. Once both schema S1/2 deployed then starts the application traffic on both.

We can include the trigger disable and enable part while deployment to fix this error. I mean Divert the traffic to S2, Disable the trigger of S1, deploy the S1 changes and enable the trigger. Same approach for S2.

@pappukumar, It's still not clear why you have schemas with triggers on tables owned by other schemas, or even what those triggers are doing.
